# Is it Possible to ignore expected parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

```
.Net
    if (ssn.contains("x))
    {
    cmd.parameters.addwithvalue(nothing just ignore);
    }
```

-

```
Stored Procedure Select
case when ssn is null then '' else case when ssn = '' then '' else 'xxxxx' + right(rtrim(ssn),4)
```

-

```
Stored Procedure Update
@currentuser varchar(30),
@ssn varchar(11) = NULL

AS
set [ssn] = [@ssn]
where [currentuser] = [@currentuser]
```

When I read the value i get what I want xxx-xx-1234 but now that value exist in my textbox and I dont want the user to click update and save xxx-xx-1234 to the database. What is the best way to handle that?

Comment: Is it possible to simply not call the proc if ssn contains x?

Comment: no as I need to save other values on the form

Comment: Please show some example code of how the stored procedure currently works, and say how you want it to work.

Comment: my question John was even though I have a stored procedure expecting a parameter is their a way to tell in .net to just ignore this parameter. Nothing wrong with my stored procedure

Comment: I edited the question hopefully make it more clear sorry John

Answer (score 0):

If you declare a stored procedure with a default value, like in your case:

```
@ssn varchar(11) = NULL
```

you don't have to pass anything to it if you don't need to. Just *don't do*

```
cmd.parameters.addwithvalue
```

for it, in fact simple skip it when adding parameters for the stored procedure and the parameter will not be "expected", Value of `NULL` will be assigned to it by default.

But if you simple don't want to do the update - well don't. Check the textbox for specific value and if it is incorrect - skip the call to DB update.